# How to target form elements other than by id, class or screen location?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, automation, autoit

I am trying to fill out a form using Internet Explorer. The webpage contains no id's nor class names. So currently I move the mouse to a relative position based on the size of the screen. But this screen resolution dependency is undesired.

Given the webpage's (internal website) lack of classes/ids, how to target its HTML form inputs, text areas, combo boxes, drop downs, date pickers, and buttons other than by screen location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate all `input` elements to identify the ones you need :

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com")
$oAs = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
$i = 1
For $oA In $oAs
   _IEPropertySet($oA, "innertext", $i)
   $i = $i + 1
Next
```

Next you could use the `$i` variable to set the right values. In this example the Google search field is the fourth `input` element so you could fill it out this way:

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com")
$oAs = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
$i = 1
For $oA In $oAs
   If $i = 4 Then _IEPropertySet($oA, "innertext", "MyValue")
   $i = $i + 1
Next
```

Comment: My apologies. It did, NEARLY perfectly. It does work in the sense that it will work in a practical situation. It doesn't work for me on an internal website for some reason. (Intranet) Any ideas?